# ListView is displaying text in white

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-edittext

I have a `listView` which populates entries fine from the `MainActivity`. The text comes out in black and everything is displaying as it should.

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, util.hashList(filtered, context), R.layout.listview_activity, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

I've added a new activity called `FilterActivity` so when I click a button on the `MainActivity` it loads up the `FilterActivity` using Intent.

```
        case R.id.action_filter:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
```

Once the Apply button in this `FilterActivity` is pressed the list is passed back to the Main Activity and the `FilterActivity` is closed.

```
context = this;
....
Main.FilteredSearch(filteredList, context);
            finish();
```

So now I'm back in the `MainActivity` I apply the same logic as before:

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, util.hashList(filtered, context), R.layout.listview_activity, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

However for some reason, this time, the text is coming out all white.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

I've had it before where I was using `getApplicationContext`, but I'm not using that this time and I've tried using `MainActivity.this`, `this`, `context`, `getApplicationContext` and `getBaseContext`. It either crashes on a `nullException` or just gives me the white text.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I could fix the issue?

Comment: I can get around it by manually applying a colour to the text fields. But I still don't understand why this is happening if I just leave the colour empty as it works fine when loading the list straight from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Post the code for `Main.FilteredSearch()`